# How to reactively get currently logged-in user in angular-meteor and ionic?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

I want `$scope.me` to be reactively represent the currently logged-in user, so that when a user logs out and logs back in as another, this variable is updated.  Right now when a user logs out and logs back in as another user, the old value of `$state.me` persists.  Once the page is reloaded this value is corrected.  How do I fix this?

Here is my working, crappy solution in the controller:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
    if($rootScope.currentUser)
        $scope.me = $rootScope.currentUser;

});
```

This worked, but reset the variable every time the user transitioned to this state... an ugly non-meteor solution.

Here is my current attempt:

```
$scope.me = ($scope.$meteorCollection(function(){
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()});
}))[0];
```

This should work, since Meteor.userId() is reactive, and should force it's parent function to re-run when it changes, thus correcting `$scope.me` in realtime... but it doesn't.

Instead `$scope.me` is updated to the sanitized profile of the old user... meaning nothing but their `_id` and `profile` are visible.  This is telling me that `$scope.$meteorCollection` is rerunning, but with an old value of `Meteor.userId()`.

What am I missing? Thank you!

*** EDIT ***
Here's a twist

```
$scope.me = ($scope.$meteorCollection(function(){
    console.log("$scope.me reset to "+Meteor.userId());
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()});
}))[0];
```

prints the **NEW** user's ID to console when the user switches, but still returns the old user even though the query is re-run with correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
$meteor.autorun($scope, function(){
    var user = (Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).fetch())[0];
    if( user != null ){
        $scope.me = user;
    }
});
```

[`$meteor.autorun`](http://angular-meteor.com/api/utils) automatically reruns reactive dependencies included within the function.  In this case, `Meteor.userId()`.  Thus whenever that is changed by meteor, the function body re-runs, setting `$scope.me` to the current user if one is logged in.

Thank you to JacobWuzHere for the tips!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `$rootScope.currentUser` instead of trying to bake your own solution? Angular-Meteor [automatically creates this $rootScope object for you](http://angular-meteor.com/api/auth), and the docs say that it is reactive.

Another possible solution would be to use the `$meteor.autorun` convenience method, but instead of autorunning based on a change in a $scope variable, you could have something like `if(Meteor.userId())` or `if(Meteor.user())`.

As a matter of fact, this is what Angular-Meteor is doing under the covers anyway if you [look at the source code](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/blob/5c5ab1c20820821e37e3204d2bdbe9fb156da8cf/modules/angular-meteor-user.js#L74).

From the [docs](http://angular-meteor.com/api/utils):

```
// Updated to check for deep equality on the getReactively() call
$meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
     $scope.userForScore = $scope.$meteorObject(Userinfo, 
        {user_id: $scope.getReactively('currentUser', true)._id}
     );// Ultimately searches up scope chain for $rootScope.currentUser._id
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.  ```$scope.me = $rootScope.currentUser;``` was the first thing I tried, and in practice doesn't reactively update, I have to reload the app once logged in as the new user for the value to correct itself.  Strange though, this shouldn't happen considering the source code...

Comment: Reloading the app seems like it could be an expensive way to solve the problem.

Have you tried using a [login hook](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin) provided by the accounts system to try to reset $scope.me? 

Depending on which router you are using, you might be able to force the resolution of some variable or service before the scope is created.

 In that case you could use the convenience methods `$meteor.waitForUser()` or `$rootScope.loggingIn` as a cue to re-assign to $scope.me

Comment: A solid solution, my only issue is that this is non-reactive.  If a user's information changes while they are logged in, those changes won't be reflected since there is no login hook to trip.

Comment: Good point -- reason is because I was not checking deep equality in my `$scope.getReactively()` statement.  I am updating my answer with the revised solution -- curious to see if it works for you. I think it might be more performance given that your answer below seems to be duplicating some of the work that Angular-Meteor is already doing for us.